# How to convert this Three.js call?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to convert some 2013 code using three.js to the current version. The .positionY function is no longer supported on the DirectionalLight.position. How would this be done with version 115?

```
light.position = new THREE.Vector3(-10000.0, 0, 0);
light.position.**rotateY**(scope.config.sunlightDirection*(Math.PI/180.0)).normalize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .positionY function

Um, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Such a method has never existed.

I suggest you use [Object3D.rotateY()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.rotateY). Besides, avoid to assign a new instance of `Vector3` to your light's `position` property. Use this pattern:

```js
light.position.set( x, y, z );
light.rotateY( angle );
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me look deeper into the code to find that they had extended the Vecror3 object with the .rotate function.